# Create a bash function with parameters to use as an alias

Tags: bash, alias, functions

I have realised that my folders follow a specific structure and wanted to access them with cd faster, so I tried to make this alias / function that would behave like this:

```
cdc glm 03
```

would be equivalent to

```
cd ~/Documents/7glm/week03
```

And I tried defining such function (in ./bashrc) but it does not work. Running it does not paste the parameters:

```
cd ~/Documents/7/week
```

The function:

```
cdc () {
    if [ $# -lt 2 "$1" ]; then
        echo  "Usage: cdc <folder_name> <folder_number>"
    else
        folder_name="$1"
        folder_number="$2"
        cd ~/Documents/7"$foldername"/week"$foldernumber"
    fi
}
```

What am I doing wrong (very new to bash)?

Thanks!

Comment: Compare `folder_name` with `foldername` ... see anything different? Also `folder_number` and `foldernumber`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to take care of two issues:

- The first being too many arguments inside the test brackets `[ ... ]` around the `-lt` operator ... Namely `2 "$1"`.
- The second being inconsistent parameter naming in setting and expansion ... e.g. `folder_name` and `"$foldername"`.

... and your function should, accordingly, be:

```bash
cdc () {
    if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
        echo  "Usage: cdc <folder_name> <folder_number>"
    else
        folder_name="$1"
        folder_number="$2"
        cd ~/Documents/7"$folder_name"/week"$folder_number"
    fi
}
```